# How jQuery assign value to 'this' on each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know, how jQuery assign a value to `this`. I tried as follow, but I am getting an error saying that `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

```js
let each = function(o, callback) {
    let keys = Object.keys(o);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        (function() {
            this = o[keys[i]];
            callback();
        })();
    }
}
```

In jQuery

```js
$("p").each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: you can't assign to `this`

Comment: With `.call` ..

Comment: then, how jquery `this` point to the current looping object?

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's what I was looking for. Thank you.